# How can I cast a 'string-array' from an XML to a string array in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to make a `ListView` that reads from an array written in the default 'string' XML. My thought is that when I make an array adapter in the Java class, I cannot directly refer the adapter to an XML value. The adapter requests a Java value, which brings up the most important part of my question: How do I cast an XML string-array into a Java string array?

Here is my (relevant) code so far:

XML:

```
<string-array name="courseNames">
    <item>Lesson 1</item>
    <item>Lesson 2</item>
    <item>Lesson 3</item>
    <item>Lesson 4</item>
    <item>Lesson 5</item>
    <item>Lesson 6</item>
</string-array>
```

Java:

```
ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewID);

lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.array.courseNames));
```

But I cannot place `courseNames` as an argument as it requires a Java array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<string-array name="courseNames">
    <item>Lesson 1</item>
    <item>Lesson 2</item>
    <item>Lesson 3</item>
    <item>Lesson 4</item>
    <item>Lesson 5</item>
    <item>Lesson 6</item>
</string-array>
```

In this case, you can use:

```
List<String> Lines = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.courseNames));
```

Comment: I tried this but it still does not show the course names in the graphical layout. Edit: Nevermind, it is NOT showing in the graphical layout but it does show up when tested on mobile. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, you wont get a listview populated on the studio unless its executed on an emulator or device! mark it as answer if this was helpful! :)